# how to plot lines in 3d graph in R

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, scatter-plot, scatter3d

I have these two 3d graphs made in R, with two different functions:

```
x <- c(0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450)
y <- c(0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450) 
z <- c(1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1)

plot_ly(x=x,y=y,z=z)
scatterplot3d(x, y, z)
```

I would like to plot in these two graphs, the following lines and the intersection area between them:

**Lines plotted in both graphs**

[image: Lines plotted in both graphs]

Comment: you could use lines3d() or points3d() with type="l" from the package rgl

Comment: I'm not clear what are you asking but, plot_ly and scatterplot3d do the same just by different means. If you want to add a 3D line in plotly use: data <- data.frame(x=x,y=y,z=z);
plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the lines and intersection with plotly, something like this will do:

```
library(scatterplot3d)
library(plotly)

x <- c(0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450)
y <- c(0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450) 
z <- c(1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1)
data <- data.frame(x=x,y=y,z=z)
line <- data.frame(x = rep(200,5), y = seq(0,500,length.out = 5), z = rep(1,5))
line2 <- data.frame(x = rep(300,5), y = seq(0,500,length.out = 5), z = rep(1,5))
rect <- data.frame(expand.grid(x= c(200,300), y =c(200,300)),z = rep(1,4) )

plot_ly() %>% 
add_trace(data=data, x=x, y=y, z=z, type="scatter3d", mode="markers") %>% 
add_trace(line, x = line$x, y = line$y, z = line$z, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines', line = list(color = 'rgb(1, 1, 1)', width = 1 , dash = 'dash', width = 4))  %>% 
add_trace(line2, x = line2$x, y = line2$y, z = line2$z, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines',  line = list(color = 'rgb(1, 1, 1)', width = 1, dash = 'dash', width = 4))   %>% 
add_trace(line, x = line$y, y = line$x, z = line$z, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines', line = list(color = 'rgb(1, 1, 1)', width = 1 , dash = 'dash', width = 4))  %>% 
add_trace(line2, x = line2$y, y = line2$x, z = line2$z, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines',  line = list(color = 'rgb(1, 1, 1)', width = 1, dash = 'dash', width = 4))%>%  
add_trace(rect,  x=rect$x, y=rect$y, z=rect$z, type="mesh3d" )
```

Result with plotly:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked just fine and it was exactly what I needed! Is there a way that I can plot the whole 3d column of this highlighted area?

Comment: do you mean plotting a prism containing the shadowed volume from 1 to 2 in the z axis?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need!

Comment: a suboptimal solution would be using add_trace to build the faces of your prims modifying the corrdinates x,y, and z e.g. add_trace(rect,  x=rect$x, y=rect$y, z=rect$z + 1, type="mesh3d" )

Comment: Hello! I tried that but it seems it only builds the area plotted before on the z = 2 coordinate, it doens't plot the prism. I might be doing something wrong and replacing it in the wrong places of the code.